# How do I get follower names instead of IDs?

Tags: api, asana

I assumed that this would provide me with the list of follower names instead of just the IDs:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects?opt_fields=name,followers&opt_expand=followers

Am I using opt_expand incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

The interplay between `opt_fields` and `opt_expand` may be confusing, as `opt_fields` currently takes precedence.

The key `name` in the `opt_fields` list it will pertain to the projects, not the followers.
Try passing just `opt_fields=followers,followers.name`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Greg – I'm really impressed at Asana's professionalism and support =D